# I want my python screenshot app to don't overwrite screenshots

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot, python-imaging-library

I have this code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageGrab
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button, Listener
import pynput
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import os.path

root = Tk()
root.title("PyScreenshot")
root.geometry("124x79")

current = set()

global save_path
save_path = "C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\Screenshot 1.png"

global nr
nr = 0

def ss():
    global nr
    nr += 1
    global save_path
    save_path = "C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\Screenshot " + str(nr) + ".png"
    root.withdraw()
    time.sleep(1)
    snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    box = (0, 91, 1679, 1011)
    snapshot.crop(box)
    snp = snapshot.crop(box)
    snp.save(save_path)
    root.deiconify()

def survivss():
    global nr
    nr += 1
    save_path = "C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\Surviv Screenshot " + str(nr) + ".png"
    root.withdraw()
    time.sleep(1)
    snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    box = (300, 255, 1407, 856)
    snapshot.crop(box)
    snp = snapshot.crop(box)
    snp.save(save_path)
    root.deiconify()

def fullss():
    global nr
    nr += 1
    save_path = "C:\\Users\\Bogdan\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\Screenshot " + str(nr) + ".png"
    root.withdraw()
    time.sleep(1)
    snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    snapshot.save(save_path)
    root.deiconify()

b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Screenshot", command = ss)
b1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

b2 = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Surviv Screenshot", command = survivss)
b2.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

b2 = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Fullscreen Screenshot", command = fullss)
b2.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my screenshot app made in python, using tkinter and pillow.
I press a button, the tkinter window dissapears, takes a screenshot and appears back.

My screenshots are saved in order "Screenshot 1.png, Screenshot 2.png,etc."
But if it take a screenshot or more and I open the app again to make a new one it overwrites them
I tried to resolve it but I couldn't
Any help?

Comment: check if the file exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists

Comment: How about using the current time (e.g. `Screenshot 2018-07-23 11:22:33.png` as the file name instead of a serial number? Easy to do in Python and doesn't need any complex checking, assuming time always goes forward

Comment: Just curious, did you actually write this code yourself, or are you using someone else's code?

Comment: @shevron do you have to _assume_ that? I thought I knew time always goes forward. ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ philosophy and hard core physics aside, that depends on how good your NTP setup is :P

Comment: Yes, that is my code, I written all of it.

Comment: @shevron Good idea, I will test that.

Comment: Thanks @shevron, it worked and I like that idea.
It's solved